# When using "f(x)" function notation, is it assumed that variable inputs are measured/calculated relative to the origin?

Tags: statistics, functions, notation

I am considering the derivation of the Gaussian distribution presented here (the famous dart throwing thought experiment):
https://www.eee.hku.hk/~msang/Gaussian.pdf

The author of the proof accounts for the possibility that one could be aiming their dart at an arbitrary point - not necessarily the origin - (μ,μ) and alters the notation of the probability density functions [p(x), p(y)] --> [p(x+μ), p(y+μ)]. For some reason, I'm hung up and confused by this symbolic notation.

Conceptually, I understand that the Gaussian function is shifted by μ units in the Cartesian plane and that the mean of the bell curve will be centered at the point (μ,μ) rather than the origin; or more generally the "origin" of the function does not coincide with the "Cartesian origin" (0,0). I also understand that I could substitute [x' = x+μ, y' = y+μ] and the derivation would proceed as if the function was centered at the "Cartesian origin". My first hangup is that the above conceptual understanding presumes prior knowledge of the function which will not always be available in a derivation.

My second hangup is that when I see "f(x)" notation my mind translates the symbolic to something along the lines of "Given x as input, the output is equal to [some mathematical expression defined in terms of 'x']" So, regardless of translation in the plane (or n-space for higher dimension functions), I would still expect the input to the function to be x (or q or whatever the variables under consideration are) and not an input of the form x+μ; therefore, I expect whatever equation results from the derivation to be equated to "f(x)" and not "f(x+μ)"

The only philosophical justification I could come up with to resolve my confusion with the notation is that "f(x)" notation assumes that the input to the function is measured/calculated/computed relative to the origin (0,0) and whenever a function is translated in space the input variable inside the parentheses of the short hand notation "f(x)" must be modified to reflect the translation. Am I mistaken?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: $f(x+a)$ is a shift, or translation, to the right or left depending on the sign of $a$. Maybe reviewing some analytic geometry and studying specific examples of graphs (e.g. $x^2$ vs $(x+a)^2$ vs $x^2 +a$) will clear your confusion.

Comment: Your "intuition" is not so wrong... The *notation* $f(x)$ is a symbol: its main goal is to specify that the function $f$ has only one argument (the *input*). From this point of view, $x$ is only a place-holder: it has nothing to do with e.g. the cartesian $x$-axis. A more "sophisticated" notation is $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, meaning that the function $f$ has only one argument that is a real number and has as values (the *output*) real numbers

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I gladly recognize and do no dispute what has been presented here. Mauro, thank you for clarifying the more "sophisticated" notation for functions. I have seen it before but wasn't sure how to read it until now. I realize that I have mischaracterized my confusion. I am actually confused at the authors assumption that [f(x), f(y)] notion implies that one is aiming at the origin (0,0). Why should this be the case? Why should I have to alter "f(x)" notation [f(x), f(y) --> f(x+μ), f(y+μ)] to account for aiming somewhere other than the origin?

Comment: This is why I concluded that "f(x)" notation implicitly implies measuring the input relative to the origin.